# Python vlookup ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I see that other people asked the same question before but I didn't find anyone in exactly the same situation. I am new to python and also new here so please take it easy on me.

I have a dataframe (created inside a function, if that's important). I am making sure that it was properly created by looking at its tail:

```
lastrow = df.tail(1)

print(lastrow, '\n')
```

The output (omitting a few columns) is:

```
          date    exdate  strike  
5693  20121102  20131220    1475
```

As you see, the first column is called 'date'. Then I do the following, not b/c it makes any sense but b/c I wanted to do something else and decided to do what I thought would be guaranteed to work b/c I used the same technique inside the function where df was created and it worked just fine:

```
lastdate = lastrow.date

Strike  = df[df.date == lastdate].strike.values[0]
```

The full error message is:

> File "C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 70, in new_method
> return method(self, other)
> File "C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py", line 40, in **eq**
> return self._cmp_method(other, operator.eq)
> File "C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 5617, in _cmp_method
> raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

First of all, I am super confused as to how the same piece of code works 'there' but not 'here'. And, because it works in other context I'm not even sure that "what am I doing wrong?" is the right question. Second, I don't understand what the message is supposed to tell me. (Reminds me of my first steps in C++.) For practical purposes, I need to know what to do to make it work.

Comment: `df.tail(1).date` still returns a data frame object. So you could do something like `lastdate = df.tail(1).date.iloc[0]`

Comment: Actually, amending my last comment: better is probably `Strike = df[df.date == df.iloc[-1,0]].strike.values[0]`

Comment: @Mako212 

Combining two of your versions, I tried

lastdate = lastrow.date.values[0]

and it worked! Thanks!